# How to calucate a RTP running timestamp?

Tags: linux, timestamp, audio-streaming, rtp

I am confused on how to calculate the RTP timestamp.

I understand the first packet's timestamp is a randomly selected value. And then something to the effect of "the time stamp for the next packets are given by the sum of previous timestamps and time taken to produce first byte of current packet". I interpret this statement as some sort of latency value calculated at runtime, between first receiving the/a packet and some epoch time when the packet is consumed and/or produced, processed, etc.

My incoming audio data specification are:

- 44100Hz sampling rate
- 16-bit sample size
- 1 channel
- 46 samples coming in every 1ms (pre-mixed)
- 46 samples going out every 1ms (post mixed)

(TMI: using embedded Ubuntu PREEMPT_RT kernel, sockets in c/c++, with PTPv2 setup with a grandmaster clock)

Anyone have ideas?

I don't know what to expect.